# Syncing packages/configs/installation between computers

Tags: fedora, scripting, virtual-machine

**Scenario:**

Two different computers connected to the internet.

**Problem:**

As both are used as workstation they should have the same setup packages, installs from net, configs.

**Possible solutions**

Creating huge installation scripts (pros: full control, cons: no versioning, error prone)

Virtual machines with possible VGA-passthrough for good desktop experience.

Pros, can create snapshots, consistens (not as error prone), cons: difficult to setup, hardware dependent.

**Improvements?**

Is there any other possible ways I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Use config management like Ansible, Puppet, or Chef to manage the installed package set and configuration. That's what these systems are *for*.

Comment: On the one hand, I feel a bit apologetic that this answer is so terse. But that's really because there's a wealth of information available on the topic — books and books!